# math functions with floor

Tags: php

This bit of code:

```
$hour = 2.2;
    if (floor($hour) > 1) {
        $str = $str . floor($hour) . " hours";
    }
    else if (floor($hour) === 1) {
        $str = $str . floor($hour) . " hour";
    }
echo $str;
```

Will output: `2 hours`

However, this bit:

```
$hour = 1.2;
    if (floor($hour) > 1) {
        $str = $str . floor($hour) . " hours, ";
    }
    else if (floor($hour) === 1) {
        $str = $str . floor($hour) . " hour ";
}
echo $str;
```

Will **not** output `1 hour`, because the condition for the `else if` does not match for some reason. Why is that?

Comment: You are using strict comparison. float and integer are different data types.

Comment: Look at the function signature: `float floor ( float $value )`. But anyways, personally I would both see them of type number and so it would be better if that worked IMO (that's me speaking after coding a lot of JavaScript ;)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floor returns a float, you're testing for an integer.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

Edit for clarity:

```
<?php
$str = "";
$hour = 1.2;
    if (floor($hour) > 1) {
        $str = $str . floor($hour) . " hours, ";
    }
    else if ((int) floor($hour) === 1) {
        $str = $str . floor($hour) . " hour ";
}
echo $str;

?>
```

Comment: ``Returns the next lowest integer value by rounding down value if necessary. ``

Comment: @hoverhand: "The return value of floor() is still of type float..."

Comment: A bit more detail: the `===` checks if type *and* value match.  Floor is a float, `1` is an integer.  Try `1.0` and you might have more luck.

Comment: Rather than calling `floor()` 4 times on the same number, you should probably assign it to a variable. Sure it doesn't matter in such a small example but it's still good practice.